# Props are showing "undefined" when on click to send props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple react app and I am beginner. I am trying to send `state` as `props` to another `component` But when I access props like `this.props.name` then it is showing **undefined**.

App.js:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
         fields : {
            name : '',
        }
    }

    updateField = evt => {
     const fields = Object.assign({}, this.state.fields);
    fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    console.log(evt.target.value)
    this.setState({fields})
    }

    render() {
        return(
             <div>
                <form>
                  <input 
                     name="name" 
                     id="name_id" 
                     onChange={this.updateField} 
                     value={this.state.fields.name} 
                  />
                </form>
                <Link to='/second_component'><SecondComponent name={this.state.fields} />Submit</Link>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/second_component' element={<SecondComponent/>} />
      </Routes>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

class SecondComponent extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
        <div style={{color: "white"}}>
          {console.log(this.props.name)}        
      </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Home;
```

I have tried many times but it is still not working. When I try to console.log then it is showing "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;` to `fields.name = evt.target.value;` and `name={this.state.fields}` to `name={this.state.fields.name}`. Should work.

Comment: Now, It is not even updating value in `input` field

Comment: @user19652801 Here is working example (no routing): https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-roentgen-kjzgqy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank You very Much, It worked, I have a question, Is defining `state={}` (like I did) better or `useState` (like you did) better ?

Comment: @user19652801 Nowdays everybody use a functional components with `useState`. Class components only for a special cases like [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).